# How to use fontforge features in detail to get convert and get web ready font in ttf

Tags: node.js, fonts, font-face, webfonts, fontforge

I have created a wrapper to use fontforge in nodejs

index.ts

```
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    
    export const  convert = (src, dst, options, callback) => {
    if(typeof options === 'function') {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
    }
    
    const forgeScriptPath = './src/fontforge/forge.sh';
    console.log('dirr--', forgeScriptPath);
    const command = 'fontforge -script "' + forgeScriptPath + '" "' + src + '" "' + dst + '"';
    exec(command, callback);
    };
```

forge.sh

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/fontforge
    Open($1);
    Generate($2);
    Quit(0);
```

My actual code which will take broken ttf as input and return correct ttf

```
    convert('src/received/test3.ttf', 'src/destination/test3.ttf', {}, function (err: any) {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
            return;
            }
        response.json({ message: 'success' });
    });
```

The above code is working great, I need to achieve these below points while converting the font to web ready ttf

1. The system should fix Truetype Hinting
2. The system should fix the GASP table of fonts
3. The system should fix missing glyphs (spaces and hyphens)
4. The system should auto-adjust vertical vetrics
5. The system should be able to subset fonts based on character input

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your question consists of five separate question rather than single one.

Comment: @AndreyOzornin Yeah they are the sub-points interlinked to each other and asking 5 different question would not be feasible and make sense to understand the whole story.